# Calling method from another object

Tags: objective-c

Sample code below.  Basically, in the code below, Game creates a bunch of objects called of type DragView.  From within these DragView objects when touchesBegin is fired, I need it to call back to a method adjustScore within Game to adjust the score.

```
@interface Game : UIViewController
{
}
@end

@Implementation Game

DragView *dragger;

- (void)loadView
{
dragger = [[DragView alloc] initWithFrame:dragRect];  
    //simplified...code actually makes lots of these
}

+ (void) adjustScore
 {
NSLog(@"This is called from within DragView");
//does some more stuff…
}


@end


@interface DragView : UIImageView
{
CGPoint startLocation;
}
@end

@implementation DragView

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{   
NSLog(@"Touched");

///// help needed here to call "adjustScore" in Game above /////

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`adjustScore` is a class method.  Just use:

```
[Game adjustScore];
```

Comment: That what I tried, but I get an error that states 'use of undeclared identifier "Game"'.

Comment: Then you need to make sure you have an `#import "Game.h"` or `@class Game` someplace in that translation unit.

Comment: Did you declared + (void)adjustScore; method in your class interface? I mean Game.h file

Comment: That was it, I needed to use @class in my case.  THANKS